# Distance to the ocean

Tags: geography, geographics

Given a `GeoPosition`, what is the recommended method to calculate its distance from the ocean?

---

**EDIT**

As an example, Atlanta is `350 km` from the Atlantic ocean, but where is that actual location? It would be nice to not have to specify an ocean by name as well.

```
GeoDistance[Entity["City", {"Atlanta", "Georgia", "UnitedStates"}], 
 Entity["Ocean", "AtlanticOcean"]]
```

> Quantity[349.84438296049916, "Kilometers"]

```
GeoGraphics[{Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], 
  GeoMarker[Entity["City", {"Atlanta", "Georgia", "UnitedStates"}], 
   "Alignment" -> Bottom]}, 
 GeoCenter -> Entity["City", {"Atlanta", "Georgia", "UnitedStates"}], 
 GeoRange -> Quantity[600, "Kilometers"], 
 GeoBackground -> "Coastlines"]
```

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably can make this more elegant, but here's what I've got so far:

```
atlanta = Entity["City", {"Atlanta", "Georgia", "UnitedStates"}];
nearestOcean = First@GeoNearest[Entity["Ocean"], atlanta];
oceanPoints = Flatten[EntityValue[nearestOcean, "Polygon"][[1]]["Data"], 1];
nearestCoastalPoint = Nearest[oceanPoints, EntityValue[atlanta, "Coordinates"]]
(* {{32.52, -80.8324}} *)
```

Augmenting your GeoGraphics:

```
GeoGraphics[
  {Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], 
   GeoMarker[atlanta, "Alignment" -> Bottom], 
   GeoMarker[GeoPosition[nearestCoastalPoint], "Alignment" -> Bottom]},
   GeoCenter -> atlanta, 
   GeoRange -> Quantity[600, "Kilometers"], 
   GeoBackground -> "Coastlines"]
```

The point doesn't look like it's quite on the coast, but maybe the plot just doesn't show sufficient detail at this scale.

**EDIT**

The option `GeoBackground -> "Coastlines"` reduces the precision of the plot. If I try this,

```
GeoGraphics[
  {Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], 
   GeoMarker[GeoPosition[nearestCoastalPoint], "Alignment" -> Bottom]},
   GeoCenter -> nearestCoastalPoint, 
   GeoRange -> Quantity[50, "Kilometers"]]
```

It does indeed seem like this point could be consdidered to be on the coast.

Comment: `GeoGraphics[{
  Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]
  , GeoMarker[atlanta, "Alignment" -> Bottom]
  , GeoMarker[GeoPosition[nearestCoastalPoint]
   , "Alignment" -> Bottom],
  GeoDisk[atlanta, Quantity[350, "Kilometers"]]
  }
 , GeoCenter -> atlanta
 , GeoRange -> Quantity[400, "Kilometers"]
 , GeoBackground -> "Coastlines"
 ]` suggests otherwise, but this could be a projection issue.

Comment: Thanks @lericr, I will have to study this solution, especially the polygon part further.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility: Take a position for your city:

```
a = GeoPosition@Entity["City", {"Atlanta", "Georgia", "UnitedStates"}]
(* GeoPosition[{33.7629, -84.4227}] *)
```

Then take the points of the US boundary (I'm skipping the nearestOcean computation performed in the accepted solution):

```
us = First[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]["Polygon"]]
```

Compute the closest of those points:

```
q = First[Nearest[us, p]]
(* GeoPosition[{31.8109, -81.3837}] *)
```

Check that the distance is approximately what you obtained initially:

```
GeoDistance[p, q, UnitSystem -> "Metric"]
(* Quantity[357.609, "Kilometers"] *)
```

The difference is due to the fact that the original computation was performed with the polygon of Atlanta, while we used a central point.